# .on() function not working for Ajax Loaded Form in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

So I am loading a form by doing the following in the **index.html**.

```
 $(".add-cell").click(function(ev) { // for each edit contact url
        ev.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation
        var url = $(this).data("form"); // get the contact form url
        $("#cell-modal").load(url, function() { // load the url into the modal
            $(this).modal('show'); // display the modal on url load
        });
        return false; // prevent the click propagation
    });
```

This loads a form located in a file **add.html**. This is the form:

```
 <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>{{l_name}}, <small>new cell</small></h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="cell-form" action="/cells/add/{{l_name}}/{{l_id}}/" method="post">   
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ cell_form.as_table }}
     </form>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
     <input class="btn btn-success submit" type="submit" id="cell_submit" value="Submit" />
     <input type="button" name="cancel" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" value="Close"/>
 </div>
```

Now, in my **index.html** I have this code:

```
 $('.cell-form').on('submit', function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: $(this).attr('method'), 
            url: this.action, 
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            context: this,
            success: function(data, status) {
               //Do stuff
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

This code works, and this script is located in the **index.html**, not in **add.html**. However, why is this code, for the button in the **add.html** not working when placed in the **index.html**?:

```
    $("#cell_submit").on('click', function(event){
        alert("LOL");
    });
```

I would like to place my JS in the index.html... not in the add.html.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element to which you attach the event has to exist on the DOM. You'll need to use something like this

```
$("#cell_modal").on('click', '#cell_submit', function(event){
    alert("LOL");
});
```

For more information about this, please check the section **Direct and delegated events** [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to start by selecting the document. It should look like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#cell_submit', function(event){
    alert("LOL");
});
```